# Many postDelayed handlers with different delays (around 2.000)

Tags: android, android-handler

My app receives messages and has to schedule multiple replies one after another each with a different delay. What is the best way to have about 2000 delayed tasks with different delays? It seems like Android can't run that much handlers at the same time due to limited ressources.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Code *simplified:*

```
class TimedTask extends TimerTask { //runs every 10 seconds and checks for new contacts in queue to reply to (contacts can go up to 500 ones)
         SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SendMessagesService.this);
         String contacts = sp.getString("contacts", "");   //queued by another Thread

         String contacts_array[] = contacts.split(",");

         for (String contact : contacts_array) {
                 Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    String message = sp.getString("message1","");  //there are different messages with different delays, depending on which were already sent

                                    ReceiveContactsAdapter mDbHelper = new ReceiveContactsAdapter(SendMessagesService.this);
                                    mDbHelper.open();
                                    mDbHelper.sendMessages(message, contact);
                                    mDbHelper.close();
                                }
                            }, delay); //delay depends on which message will be sent
         }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use a queue to solve this ?

Comment: @king Queue would be blocking, since different task have different delay time

Comment: Please provide your (non functional) code using Handlers so we get an idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: i agree with @dipdipdip, please provide some code to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: @dipdipdip I added a simplified piece of the code. Hope it helps. Generally the code works, it just struggles with too many messages which have to be scheduled.

Comment: can't you have a listener on that shared pref instead of opening it everytime to see if there is something new?

Comment: @njzk2 I think it changes too often, but the check for new contacts probably isn't a problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thread.sleep(milisec) instead. It delays the thread for the particular time.

```
 @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            ////
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {

                }
        }
    })).start();
```

Comment: I think that doesn't work, because many tasks need different delays, it's not possible to run them together

Comment: Ah okay I know. Is this more ressource efficient?

Comment: This solution will be same as using multiple handler with different time delay.

Comment: @Sumit Can you explain why? :)

Comment: android doesn't has to deal with handler objects and multiple thread can run at the same time using this. You should read these stuffs yourselves.

Comment: But why to use runOnUiThread? I don't want to update the UI. Doesn't it block the UI?

Comment: it was just an example to show u if u lateron wanted to update the ui

Comment: What is the alternative? Sorry for this question ^^

Comment: alternative for what >

Comment: You need to use the uithread if u want to update the ui theres no alternatibe for that. However you can save the data in a variable and later on update the interface.

Comment: I meant if I dont want to update the UI, just run it in background ;)

Comment: @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                { //codehere }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {

                }
        }
    })).start();